# How to deal with typeclass constraint in class member function

Tags: haskell, typeclass

GHCI complains about the types of `k` and `a` inside of `(k * a, k * b)`. My guess is it doesn't know that `k` is a `Num` but I don't know how to specify that.

```
module Point where

data Point x y = Point (x, y)

class Vector v where
  add :: v -> v -> v
  sub :: v -> v -> v
  mul :: Num k => k -> v -> v

instance (Num a, Num b) => Vector (Point a b) where
  add (Point (a, b)) (Point (c, d)) = Point (a + c, b + d)
  sub (Point (a, b)) (Point (c, d)) = Point (a - c, b - d)
  mul k (Point (a, b)) = Point (k * a, k * b)
```

Comment: It does know that, but it does not know that `a` and `b` are the *same* type. In Haskell the operands of `(+)`, `(-)`, `(*)`, etc. all have the same type. There is no `(+) :: Int -> Double -> Double`.

Comment: Ok maybe I should define Point to have the same type for x and y.

Comment: not only for `x` and `y`, also for `k` and `x`, and thus `k` and `y`.

Comment: The tuple is redundant; it's just an unnecessary layer of indirection. `data Point x y = Point x y` or (better) `data Point x = Point x x` is sufficient.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Is there a way to specify that `k`, `x`, and `y` must all be the same type?

Comment: @BradyDean Sure: `data Point x = Point x x` says that `Point` has two values *of the same type* (and that type is `x`).

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your `mul` signature says that a `v` can be multiplied by *any* type `k` which has a `Num` instance: `Int`, `Double`, `Complex Double`, etc. etc.

But for vector spaces you want something very different: to say that there is a specific `k` for each `v`. This can be done in two ways (after fixing `data Point x = Point x x` as suggested in the comments):

1. using multi-parameter type class with [functional dependency](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html#functional-dependencies);
2. using [associated types](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html#associated-data-and-type-families).

I initially had given the solutions using both, but it may be more helpful to read the linked documentation and try it yourself.